# Play audio buffers generated by AVSpeechSynthesizer directly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, avspeechsynthesizer

We have a requirement for audio processing on the output of `AVSpeechSynthesizer`. So we started with using the `write` method of `AVSpeechSynthesizer` class to apply processing on top. of it. What we currently have:

```swift
var synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
var playerNode: AVAudioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
fun play(audioCue: String){
   let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: audioCue)
   synthesizer.write(utterance, toBufferCallback: {[weak self] buffer in
      // We do our processing including conversion from pcmFormatFloat16 format to pcmFormatFloat32 format which is supported by AVAudioPlayerNode
      self.playerNode.scheduleBuffer(buffer as! AVAudioPCMBuffer, completionCallbackType: .dataPlayedBack)
   }
}
```

All of it was working fine before iOS 16 but with iOS 16 we started getting this exception:

```
[AXTTSCommon] TTSPlaybackEnqueueFullAudioQueueBuffer: error -66686 enqueueing buffer
```

Not sure what this exception means exactly. So we are looking for a way of addressing this exception or may be a better way of playing the buffers.

**UPDATE:**

Created an empty project for testing and it turns out the write method if called with an empty bloc generates these logs:

[image]

Comment: If something was working and iOS 16 broke it, file a bug report.

Comment: I did on feedback assistant, but for some reason Apple does not want to react or even acknowledge it

Comment: Apple doesn't generally "react" or "acknowledge" anything. You've done what you can, which is good! Now the ball is in Apple's court.

Comment: Yea I dont have my hopes high. I reported an issue before ios 15 release as well and they still have not responded on it. Which is why this time i am looking for help from the community

Comment: Same problem here. Thank you Apple...

Comment: Has anyone figured out what that exception is? -66686 I mean? Or how to find out what it means?

Comment: -66686 is `kAudioQueueErr_BufferEmpty`

Comment: Is there a way to hide these exceptions in the console?

Comment: Was this fixed yet? I am running into this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Code I have used for Swift project :

```
let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()    
let myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: message)
myUtterance.rate = 0.4
synth.speak(myUtterance)
```

Can move **let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()** out of this method and declare on top for this class and use.

**Settings to enable for Xcode14 & iOS 16 :** If you are using XCode14 and iOS16, it may be voices under spoken content is not downloaded and you will get an error on console saying identifier, source, content nil. All you need to do is, go to accessiblity in settings -> Spoken content -> Voices -> Select any language and download any profile. After this run ur voice and you will be able to hear the speech from passed text.

It is working for me now.

Comment: Actually the problem is not with `speak` method but is with `write` method